# How to pass a windows handle correctly?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, handle

I have no clue what's behind a handle and if its a big object or not. Generally I pass them a lot in my application, hence it would be kind if you could tell me how I should pass them. By value, const reference or even pointer?

Edit:
I should mention that I talk about bitmap handles. Maybe that makes a difference.

Okay [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has its own page only for the uppercase windows types.

Comment: From what I understand, a Handle is a kind of pointer itself, but in your program it is an integer which identifies some object in Windows. So the WinAPI doesn't use objects but "pointers to objects" = handles, pointing to objects in Windows (*behind* the API). So it should be totally fine to pass them around by value. Copying a handle doesn't copy the object behind it. If you want to copy the object behind the handle, the API should provide functions to do so, I think.

Comment: Okay thanks. Since it is some kind of pointer there is no need to pass them by reference i guess, is it?

Comment: Yeah. But you should wait for at least one more answer, since I'm not 100% sure ;)

Comment: @DevNoob Leemes is right, but if you wanted to check yourself, trying writing a program which outputs `sizeof(HANDLE)`, you'll find they're very small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can view a bitmap handle, an HBITMAP, as an ID. So, pass them around by value. They are pointer sized so there's no performance issues with pass by value for an HBITMAP.